# Spreading arrray elements into parameters in 3rd party function javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, microsoft-dynamics

I am building an add in in Microsoft dynamics rms HTML. need to append parameters into qsbridge function named "ShowMenu".

```
key = qsBridge.FireEvent("ShowMenu",
"My Menu",            // Caption for the menu. 
"ParmeterKeyString1", "ParameterValueString1",   // Key/value pair for the first option.
"ParmeterKeyString2",  "ParameterValueString2", // Key/value pair for the second option.
"ParmeterKeyString3", "ParameterValueString3");  // Key/value pair for the third option.
```

My array can be unknown in size

```
var my_array = ["ParamKey1","ParamValue1","ParmKey2","ParmValue2"];
```

I've tried this.

```
qsBridge.FireEvent("ShowMenu","My Menu",my_array);
```

It gave me an error.
[image]

How can i spread my_array values into function parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
qsBridge.FireEvent("ShowMenu","My Menu", ....my_array);
```

Or if that is not supported by the target browsers, you can concat all params to a single array, and use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
qsBridge.FireEvent.apply(qsBridge, ["ShowMenu","My Menu"].concat(my_array));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but their is a problem. It uses internet explorer compatible to v5 or v6 :(

Comment: That's why I've included the `apply` part which should work with older browsers.

Comment: It shows error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Comment: some information regarding this event. http://www.rite.us/Portals/0/Downloads/RMS_Customization_Guide/ShowMenu_(FireEvent).htm

Comment: Apply is supported by all versions of IE, while concat is supported since 5.5. I don't have any way of testing this.

Comment: is their any way to write loop like this. `qsBridge.FireEvent("ShowMenu","My Menu",for loop here 1,for loop here 2` ?

Comment: Not that I know of.